# How could I display ASCII of utf-8?

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, ascii

My wordpress-blog runs with UTF-8. Now I want to display just one title as ASCII because I have to send it to a payment provider.

The following PHP Snippets are not working:

```
$utf8 = 'ÄÖÜ';
$iso88591_1 = utf8_decode($utf8);
$iso88591_2 = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $utf8);
$iso88591_2 = mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```

The result is: �.

How could I display single words as ASCII (like %E4 instead of ä for example) within my utf-8 encoded Blog?

Comment: You mean [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)?

Comment: urlencode is encoding ä to %C3%A4. But I need a %E4

Comment: Convert to whichever encoding you need (one that encodes `ä` as 0xe4), then URL encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine conversion to ISO-8859-1 and url encoding, like this:

```
 $utf8 = 'ÄÖÜ';
 echo urlencode(utf8_decode($utf8));
```

output:

> %C4%D6%DC